# How can use signals as query parameters in Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, signals

I have pagination of a data table from which I get limit and offset and update requestParams$, wheт it updated -  request being executed

```
  public requestParams$ = new BehaviorSubject<{
    limit: number;
    offset: number;
  }>({
    limit: 6,
    offset: 0,
  });

  handleOnPagination(currentPage: number) {
    const { limit } = this.requestParams$.getValue();

    const newOffset = (currentPage - 1) * limit;

    this.updateRequestParams({ offset: newOffset });
  }

  private updateRequestParams(
    params: Partial<{
      limit: number;
      offset: number;
    }>
  ) {
    const value = this.requestParams$.value;
    this.requestParams$.next({ ...value, ...params });
  }

 private loadData() {
    this.requestParams$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        distinctUntilParamsChanged(['offset', 'limit']),
        tap(({ limit }) => {
          this.busy = true;
          this.paginationLimit = limit;
        }),
        switchMap(({ limit, offset }) =>
          this.service.getData({ limit, offset })
        )
      )
      .subscribe((wishesBooks)....
```

How can this code be rewritten using signals? How can this code be rewritten using signals? Has anyone had experience using signals as query parameters?

Comment: There's this [Enea_Jahollari](https://x.com/Enea_Jahollari/status/1720078134719152200?s=20) approach. But have a reason to rewrite working code.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on ngxtension library that publishes some helper utilities for signals in Angular.

Here's some utils:

- computedAsync - https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/computed-async/
- injectParams - https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/injectors/inject-params/
- injectQueryParams - https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/injectors/inject-query-params/

Here's something you can do using some of it's utilities

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { injectQueryParams } from 'ngxtension/inject-query-params';
import { computedAsync } from 'ngxtension/computed-async';

class TestCmp {
  private router = inject(Router);

  queryParams = injectQueryParams(); // returns an object with the current query params as signals

  data = computedAsync(() => { // will use switchMap under the hood by default
    const { offset, limit } = this.queryParams(); // will recompute when queryParams change
    return this.service.getData({ offset, limit }); // getData is a method that returns an Observable
  }); // returns a signal

  handleOnPagination(currentPage: number) {
    const { limit } = this.queryParams();

    this.router.navigate([], {
      queryParams: { offset: (currentPage - 1) * limit },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
  }
}
```